# Regex ignores second lookahead

Tags: php, regex

I can't understand why second output ignores `(?!B)` condition and returns `201B` instead of `20 x 1B`?

My PHP code:

```
$s_1 = '20 x 1';
$s_2 = '20 x 1B';

$pattern = '/(?<=\d)[\s]*[xX][\s]*(?=\d)(?!B)/ui';

echo preg_replace($pattern, '', $s_1); // output: 201
echo preg_replace($pattern, '', $s_2); // output: 201B
```

Comment: Is this in the context of PHP? it should be tagged accordingly. Regular expressions can differ radically from one implementation to another.

Comment: What is the expected output? What do you mean by "ignores  `(?!B)`"?

Comment: Yes, it's PHP. Expected output is `20 x 1B`

Comment: Do you want to only match when the digit is not followed with `B`? `'/(?<=\d)\s*[xX]\s*(?=\d(?!B))/ui'`? See https://ideone.com/nzWmDu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last negative lookahead should be nested inside `(?=\d)`:

```
(?<=\d)\s*[xX]\s*(?=\d(?!B))
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pEDTUp/1)

When `(?!B)` is outside as in your regex then then **zero-width assertion** is applied after matching `x` and a space. That assertion returns true because next position is a digit.